# Looking for a program that will get System Specs over the network

Tags: windows-7

Looking for a program like [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy), But one that I can run over the network without having to install / run it on each individual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use both Spiceworks (free, web based) and PDQ Inventory (free and paid versions, desktop app) for scanning on my network.

No matter what solution you pick, you will need to open ports on the clients' firewalls, usually the WMI ports.

Comment: I've briefly used spiceworks before for monitoring Switches and file servers, will it allow me to get system info from machines? eg. ammount of ram, gpu installed etc.. similar to speccy? I'll check out PDQ now as well, thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes it does. Even motherboard information, including bios versions and service/asset tags

Comment: Brilliant i will invest more time into it so, thanks again!